# Bibliometrix : Three Fields Plot (Sankey Diagram) Exports

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

Could you please advise me using Bibliometrix, how can I export the connected elements to each item in Three Fields Plot (Sankey Diagram) to a CSV file (I need an R code)?

**Example**: for the first item in middle (bibliographic coupling) I want to export the references on the left side (small h, 1973 ..., kessler mm, 1956 ... ). Also, I want to export the list of items on the right side connected to this item (science, networks, indicators). Here is this example's R code:

```
library(bibliometrix)
data(scientometrics, package = "bibliometrixData")
threeFieldsPlot(scientometrics, fields=c("CR","DE","ID"),n=c(5,5,5))
```

[image]